# Limit user be able to view a bunch of record types and only be able to create some of them

Tags: permissions, record-type

I am wondering if it is possible to limit users from being able to see A, B, C record types of one particular SObject, but only be able to create A record type? I checked the permission set settings but didn't see anything for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually straightforward

- A user can create only those recordtype(s) assigned to them in the union of their profile and permission set(s)
- A user can view any record, regardless of recordtype as long as they have record sharing to that record.  Such sharing is determined by OWD, criteria-based sharing rules, manual sharing, apex managed sharing, territories, and ownership

From the [Salesforce Security Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/permissions_record_type_access.htm)

> Record type assignment on a user’s profile or permission set (or permission set group) doesn’t determine whether a user can view a record with that record type. The record type assignment simply specifies that the user can use that record type when creating or editing a record.